# How to fix PS 2 power won't turn green?

Tags: hardware, ps2

When I power on my PS 2, it shows a red light on the reset button. When I push the button, it turns green just for a few seconds and switch back to the red light. I google about this and many suggest to check the fuse. But I can't find the schematic diagram or board diagram for PS 2 model SCPH-75006.

Comment: Not really a solution, but if you really can't fix it, you might want to consider fiddling with PCSX2, an emulator. I had to get rid of my broken PS2 a few years ago, but I still often play with my actual physical PS2 games on my PC. No need to rip the games or anything, you can just launch games directly from your CD-Drive. Of course you need a decent PC and all, just a possible alternative solution.
P.S : I couldn't find a conclusive answer about Arqade's stance on Emulator talk btw (Only that ROMs / ISOs are probably off-limits). Feel free to take down this comment if it violates it.